# jQuery submit requiring 2 clicks to run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a webpage using jQuery, HTML and php that will update information in my mySQL database, but when I click submit on the form, it doesn't run, but if I click it twice it does. How can I get this to work on a single click?

```
<body>
    <form id="homeform">
        <textarea name="editor" id="editor" rows="25" cols="80">
        </textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
        </script>
        <input type="submit" value="Update Home Page">
    </form>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $("#homeform").submit(function(event) {
            $.post( "homeupdate.php", $( "#homeform" ).serialize());
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: How do you know it is not working on the first click? May be the AJAX takes a while?

Comment: I have waited after the first click for up to 10 minutes. but it works instantly on the second click.

Comment: check your browser console to make sure first click is working or not?

Comment: @scottdominic94 Open console. Click Network. See what's happening?

Comment: your code works for me on single click also

Comment: It's calling the php file on the first click but not sending the data to the sql

Comment: that will be the problem of php code not in this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a problem on the CKEDITOR's side.
You might try to put your code inside the following:

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event)
{
     //put your code here
});
```

Comment: That did the trick! thank you very much for your help everybody! :)